# Using single letters in Microsoft Speech SDK

Tags: speech-recognition, speech-to-text, microsoft-speech-platform, microsoft-speech-api

When I just used the letters, D got confused with B, and a lot of the letters got confused with other letters, so I replaced any letter that was working incorrectly with a word or name, but as you can see, it is half of them.
I was wondering if there are any solutions where it is possible to say "D" for example, without it getting confused with a "B"?

```
sre = new SpeechRecognitionEngine(new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("sv-SE"));
Choices alphabeth = new Choices(new string[] { "Alfa", "Beta", "C", "Daniel", "Erik", "Fika", "Gustav", "Hans", "Isak", "Jan", "K", "L", "Martin", "N", "Olov", "Patrik", "Q", "Roland", "S", "T", "Ulla", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z", "Å", "Älv", "Ödla" });
```

Comment: You can use more accurate toolkit like Kaldi, it will be hard to setup though. D vs B is very hard to recognize. It is very common "e-set" problem in speech recognition.

Comment: Are you set on using Microsoft Speech? If you switch to System.Speech, using dictation you can use phrases such as "B as in Boy". You could conceivably build a grammar that allows such things in Microsoft.Speech.